# How can I put a print link/button on my project page to printout an infomation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails for my application(student register) and i need a print link/button to print out some student's information. Please what do I do?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this tag to make a print link.

```
<%= link_to 'print', 'your_link_here', :onclick => 'window.print();return false;'%>
```

Now, if you want to print a specific section, you can use media types of css

```
/*This css will only works when you print*/
@media print {
  body {
    background: #FFF;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if i misunderstand something here because this seems more like a javascript question then a rails one to me: But here is how you make a print link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;">print me</a>
```

**Note:** the `return false` is critical, otherwise the app will hung up.

You could also make a special print page with only the desired information and have window.print in the onload event like this:

```
<body onload="window.print();">
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes. It worked but I want it to only print particular section of the page. How can I get that done?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use the second method. Make a dynamic print page, so when the user clicks "Print" on the mainpage you link that to a new page print/?studentid=12345 which opens up in a new window. On the new page you put all the relevant info for the student requested and have the onload="window.print();" code in the body tag which will open up the print dialog as soon as the page has loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Include this in where you want to add the print button

```
function printPage() {
    window.print()
}
```

After that, give a link or button

```
<%= link_to "print", "#", onclick: "printPage()" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can load a print style sheet that uses "display:none" on the divs you want to hide. It has the added benefit of being styled in whatever manner you choose, and you can use it with the first example above or the "Print Me" link rather than the onload version..