# Ruby print button

Tags: ruby, printing, link-to

```
 <%= link_to "Print", 'window.print();return false;', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Trying to implement a print button but I don't know what format to use. Could anyone help me. I want it to be using the class btn btn-primary

Comment: Tried this also  <%= link_to_function("Print this Page", "javascript:print()"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the browser that you want to execute Javascript there.  So you either need to use `onClick`, which can be given via a `:onclick =>` parameter, or prefix the code with `javascript:`.

Here is a similar SO question: [How can I put a print link/button on my project page to printout an infomation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789880/how-can-i-put-a-print-link-button-on-my-project-page-to-printout-an-infomation)

Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Print", '#', class: "btn btn-primary", 
            onclick: 'window.print();return false;' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how I could generate a pdf doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are making this more complicated than it has to be. You don't need to use the `link_to` helper as you aren't doing anything that would benefit from it. Just use a simple `a` or `button` tag.

`<a onclick='window.print(); return false;' class='btn btn-primary'>Print</a>`

or

`<button onclick='window.print(); return false;' class='btn btn-primary'>Print</button>`